# Another issue: Passing argument by reference

Tags: c++, reference

So i thought i had the idea of passing by reference down, but it seems i'm still struggling with it a bit.

Here's my issue, i've been debugging my game for awhile, and i left the enemies section of my code untouched for ages. It's a long story but i thought my projectiles were doing damage to the enemies, I changed the enemies health to being very high, so i thought they were doing the damage but because of the high health, not killing it. Only now have i realised that they are not doing any damage and that the code is wrong :/

So here is were i begin:

```
void Towers::Update(std::vector<Enemies>& enemies, SDLib& lib, Map cMap)
```

Here i'm passing the enemies by reference, into my update function. Which then i go onto see if there is any enemy within range of the tower;

```
for (int numOfEnemies = 0; numOfEnemies < lib.numberOfEnemies; numOfEnemies++)
{
    float y =  pow(enemies[numOfEnemies].position.y - position.y, 2);
    float x = pow(enemies[numOfEnemies].position.x - position.x, 2);

    if (sqrt(y + x) < range && enemies[numOfEnemies].alive)
    {
        cEnemy = enemies[numOfEnemies];
        acquiredTarget = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

cEnemy (currentEnemy), then holds the enemy that's within range. After this, i then create the projectile to fire, and here is were i think i'm messing up;

```
bullet = Projectile((float)position.x, (float)position.y - 8, 8, 8, 0, 0, damage, 1, speed, cEnemy);
```

And the function arguments for that are:

```
Projectile::Projectile(float x, float y, int w, int h, int sX, int sY, int dmg, int type, float mxSpeed, Enemies bulletTarget)
{
     //....other values set. 
     target = bulletTarget;
}
```

(Target is the following)

```
Enemies target;
```

The idea here is that target should hold the reference to the initial enemy that i set it to via the function... But it isn't working as i want. 
I'm not too sure, but i'm guessing some form of pointer might be required here. It seems to be out of everything the concept i'm finding hardest to grasp *and have done for some time now.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Why would you kill your enemies ? Forgive them so you can both happily live together !

Comment: Is there some reason you're not looping over the size of the `enemies` vector?  If you changed that and looped with an iterator, you could avoid some of these problems pretty easily.  You could move the projectile instantiation/whatever into the for loop and add `acquireTarget` to the loop termination condition enabling you to get rid of that ugly `break`.  Dereferencing a non-const vector iterator gives you a reference.

Comment: When you want to pass things by reference, pass them by reference, not by value...

Comment: Also (not to prematurely optimize or anything) but you could compare `x + y` with the square of range so that you never call `sqrt()`.  Shouldn't be a big deal, but it's a game, so might as well save some computation.

Comment: Oh yeah, and you're potentially doing `enemies[numOfEnemies]` 4 times per loop.  Not that your compiler won't take care of that.  I'm just sayin'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a copy of the `Enemies` object:

- On `cEnemy = enemies[numOfEnemies];`
- When passing a value to the `Projectile` constructor, since it takes an `Enemies` by value.
- On `target = bulletTarget;`

To fix all of these, you need to consider what code "owns" an `Enemies` object and makes sure it lives long enough for all code that tries to use it.  If there is such a place, all other places should use a reference or pointer.  If not, maybe you can give the responsibility to `shared_ptr<Enemies>`.

Answer (score 0):

We are missing some information here, but one line that could cause that is:

```
cEnemy = enemies[numOfEnemies];
```

I don't know what is the type of `cEnemy` but it seems you are copying your enemy object from the list instead of just refering to it.

Did you know you can create a local reference like that:

```
Enemies& cEnemy = enemies[numOfEnemis];
```

That is, `cEnemy` will refer to the enemy in the list, and not to a copy.

If you do that, just beware, because `cEnemy` is just a reference, and if you modify your list, this reference might be silently lost.

Are you sure your `Enemies` class should be copiable ? If it should not, fixing it not to be copiable would make the compiler your best friend to find such "mistakes".

Comment: Limiting the copy constructor of `Enemies` may be a good idea, but it would require using a container type other than `vector<Enemies>`.

Comment: @aschepler You are right. I forget sometimes that not everyone can use the movable facilities that C++11 provides. Note that the OP could still wrap his `Enemies` in a shared pointer to make it more clear that he deals with unique references and still be able to store them in standard containers.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the `Enemies` argument to the `Projectile` constructor by value, and then also storing it by value.

If you want `target` to be a reference to `cEnemy`, then both will need to be references. Also note that reference members have to be initialised in the constructor's initialiser list, as they can't be reassigned in the body as your code does.

```
class Projectile 
{
public:
    Projectile(/*lots of args*/, Enemies & target) :
        target(target)
    {}

private:
    Enemies & target;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is missing some information about the type of cEnemy and how you use the target, so I'm guessing that `cEnemy` is defined as `Enemies` and you need a reference for `target` to update the correct object. In this case your problems are the following:

1. `cEnemy = enemies[numOfEnemies];` makes a copy instead of a reference
2. since `bulletTarget` is of type `Enemies` `bullet = Projectile((float)position.x, (float)position.y - 8, 8, 8, 0, 0, damage, 1, speed, cEnemy);` makes a copy
3. since `target` is type `Enemies` `target = bulletTarget;` makes a copy

References generally only take addresses when they are constructed, later assignments make copies. So to solve the first item you need to make `cEnemy` a pointer:

```
Enemies* cEnemy;
//some code
cEnemy = &enemies[numOfEnemies];
//some more code
```

The second item can be solved by defining the constructor as

```
Projectile::Projectile(float x, float y, int w, int h, int sX, int sY, int dmg, int type, float mxSpeed, Enemies& bulletTarget)
```

The third item can be solve by defining target as a reference and initialising it in an initialisation list (the last part is important), making it

```
Enemies& target;
Projectile::Projectile(float x, float y, int w, int h, int sX, int sY, int dmg, int type, float mxSpeed, Enemies& bulletTarget):target(bulletTarget)
{}
```

Since assignement to references is a copy operation (only the construction of a reference takes the address, if you can't initialise `target` in the initialisation list, you need to make it a pointer:

```
Enemies* target;
Projectile::Projectile(float x, float y, int w, int h, int sX, int sY, int dmg, int type, float mxSpeed, Enemies& bulletTarget)
{  
   target = &bulletTarget;
}
```

`

Comment: Thank you ever so much! I see were i was going wrong :/ all stemming from that initial cEnemy = enemies[numOfEnemies]. 
Before-hand i did have the first 2 issues correctly done, but because i didn't solve that core, first issue i see were it was all falling now.

Comment: @Danran: You're welcome. If you find the answer helpful upvoting and/or accepting it is of course always appreciated ;)